# How did Darth Bane die?

Tags: star-wars, sith, star-wars-legends

I tried to find when and how Darth Bane died, but without luck.

I guessed he was killed by his apprentice Darth Zannah. A friend of mine told that he was killed by Yoda. Are any of these true?

How and when did Darth Bane die? I want proper source citation too.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Duel_on_Ambria

Comment: I'd point out that in all probability, Yoda was not alive at the time, and was certainly not a great Jedi Master, powerful enough to defeat Bane.

Comment: And looking it up, there was a published date for his birth (896BBY - I didn't think there was), so he was definitely not born

Comment: He died... poorly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bane was killed by his apprentice, [Darth Zannah](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Duel_on_Ambria) in 988BBY on the planet Ambria. She used a mixture of lightsaber skills (though she lost her weapon to Bane before his ultimate defeat), Dark Side [force tendrils](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_side_tendrils) and some kind of mind-fogging power on him.

At the moment of his death, he transcended physical form and attempted to seize control of her body but her force powers were too strong and he simply dissipated.

The event is described (in some considerable detail) in [Darth Bane : Dynasty of Evil](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane:_Dynasty_of_Evil)

> From a safe distance, the Iktotchi had watched the two figures [Darth Bane and Darth Zannah] from
> her dreams wage battle. She was an impartial observer, having no
> preference as to which one would emerge victorious. She only wanted to
> serve whoever proved the stronger.
>
> The conflict had been brief but intense: she had marveled at the speed
> of their blades, their movements so fast she could barely follow the
> action. She had felt the awesome power of the Force unleashed through
> bursts of lightning and the sinister tendrils that crawled up from the
> ground. She shivered in anticipation with the knowledge that she, too,
> could one day learn to wield such power.
>
> She had seen Bane knock the woman to the ground and slap her weapon
> away, only to have his arm hewn off by the touch of one of the black
> tentacles. And then there had been a flash so bright she had been
> forced to close her eyes and look away.
>
> When she looked back Bane was gone, his body reduced to a pile of ash.
> The blond woman still lay on the ground, dazed but alive. The deadly
> tendrils were nowhere to be seen.
>
> Cautiously she approached the scene. Bane's severed arm lay on the
> ground, but the rest of his body had been consumed by the crimson
> flare. In the instant before she had looked away, however, she had
> felt something.

---

Responding to internet rumours of Bane's survival, the author wrote an [FAQ for his website](http://www.drewkarpyshyn.com/spoiler.htm);

> *I thought it was pretty clear in my writing. I wrote the scene from
> Cognus’s point of view to keep you guessing to the last instant, but
> when Zannah proclaims “Darth Bane is gone. I am Darth Zannah, Dark
> Lord of the Sith and your new Master,” I thought it would be pretty
> clear.*
>
> *The whole thing with Zannah’s hand twitching was only to show
> that some part of Bane had passed through to her. How much – was he
> still “alive” in some way, or is it just a small part of his identity
> imprinted on her – was supposed to be the ambiguous part. But **I never
> wanted people to assume Bane had taken over Zannah’s body
> successfully.***

---

Note that as the whole of this story is found in an EU "Legend" novel, none of these events are considered to be part of the [accepted Star Wars canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon).

Comment: I was under the impression that it was left deliberately vague as to whether Bane was successful or not.

Comment: @IG_42 - I can't think of an instance where his force-ghost reappeared.

Comment: But did he really die??? I'll never know. Dam you Drew Karpyshyn!!!

Comment: @Hatandboots - Unless a future novel contradicts the events of this book, the very clear implication is that he died.

Comment: @Richard It was not clear at all! It was intentionally unclear in fact.

Comment: @Hatandboots - "*Bane was gone, his body reduced to a pile of ash*". I really don't see how it could be any clearer than that.

Comment: @Richard So I'm guessing you haven't read the book?

Comment: @Hatandboots - From [the author](http://www.drewkarpyshyn.com/spoiler.htm); *"I thought it was pretty clear in my writing. I wrote the scene from Cognus’s point of view to keep you guessing to the last instant, but when Zannah proclaims “**Darth Bane is gone. I am Darth Zannah, Dark Lord of the Sith and your new Master,” I thought it would be pretty clear.***

Comment: *The whole thing with Zannah’s hand twitching was only to show that some part of Bane had passed through to her. How much – was he still “alive” in some way, or is it just a small part of his identity imprinted on her – was supposed to be the ambiguous part. But I never wanted people to assume Bane had taken over Zannah’s body successfully.*

Comment: OKay this is turning into a chat, but I've never seen that quote. So if HE said it then it is pretty concrete. I always just took the twitching as an ambiguous conclusion.

Comment: I totally took the hand twitching to mean that Bane had succeeded, or to at least make you wonder.

Comment: @daryl - Oh, I agree. It's the literary equivalent of ending your film **"The End...?"**

Comment: @Valorum Whoa, whoa, whoa. Just because he wrote the book doesn't mean he understands it. If the author wants to convince me that Darth Bane didn't take over Zannah's body he's got to write another novel saying so. Comments on his homepage don't count! :)

Comment: @Hack-R - His ineptitude as an author notwithstanding, it sounds like he was quite surprised that readers were misreading his writings quite so dramatically.

Comment: @Valorum Oh, yes I agree on that. But all I'm saying is that an author, when speaking as a regular human being and not writing it in a work of fiction, can't tell us how to interpret the story, basically. Isaac Asimov said something to this effect about his own work.

Comment: @Hack-R - *"Just because you wrote it, what makes you think you have the slightest idea what it's about?"*" (echoing Umberto Eco); http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathOfTheAuthor